# Regex named capture groups in Delphi XE

Tags: regex, delphi, delphi-xe, regexbuddy

I have built a match pattern in RegexBuddy which behaves exactly as I expect. But I cannot transfer this to Delphi XE, at least when using the latest built in TRegEx or TPerlRegEx.

My real world code have 6 capture group but I can illustrate the problem in an easier example. This code gives "3" in first dialog and then raises an exception (-7 index out of bounds) when executing the second dialog.

```
var
  Regex: TRegEx;
  M: TMatch;
begin
  Regex := TRegEx.Create('(?P<time>\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})(?P<judge>.{1,3})');
  M := Regex.Match('00:00  X1 90  55KENNY BENNY');
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(M.Groups.Count));
  ShowMessage(M.Groups['time'].Value);
end;
```

But if I use only one capture group

```
Regex := TRegEx.Create('(?P<time>\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})');
```

The first dialog shows "2" and the second dialog will show the time "00:00" as expected.

However this would be a bit limiting if only one named capture group was allowed, but thats not the case... If I change the capture group name to for example "atime".

```
var
  Regex: TRegEx;
  M: TMatch;
begin
  Regex := TRegEx.Create('(?P<atime>\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})(?P<judge>.{1,3})');
  M := Regex.Match('00:00  X1 90  55KENNY BENNY');
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(M.Groups.Count));
  ShowMessage(M.Groups['atime'].Value);
end;
```

I'll get "3" and "00:00", just as expected. Is there reserved words I cannot use? I don't think so because in my real example I've tried completely random names. I just cannot figure out what causes this behaviour.

Comment: you shall report this in QC, as this is obviously a bug.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When [pcre_get_stringnumber](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/Documentation/pcre/pcre_get_stringnumber.html) does not find the name, `PCRE_ERROR_NOSUBSTRING` is returned.

`PCRE_ERROR_NOSUBSTRING` is defined in RegularExpressionsAPI as `PCRE_ERROR_NOSUBSTRING = -7`.

Some testing shows that `pcre_get_stringnumber` returns `PCRE_ERROR_NOSUBSTRING` for every name that has the first letter in the range of `k` to `z` and that range is dependent of the first letter in `judge`. Changing `judge` to something else changes the range.

As i see it there is at lest two bugs involved here. One in `pcre_get_stringnumber` and one in TGroupCollection.GetItem that needs to raise a proper exception instead of `SRegExIndexOutOfBounds`

Comment: Thanks a lot for digging in to the problem to this level. I've found a workaround solution using the TPerlRegEx library from RegexBuddy's author. This library, as I understand, form the base for XE's implementation, so I find the differences very mysterious.

Answer (score 5):

The bug seems to be in the `RegularExpressionsAPI` unit that wraps the PCRE library, or in the PCRE OBJ files that it links.  If I run this code:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, RegularExpressionsAPI;

var
  myregexp: Pointer;
  Error: PAnsiChar;
  ErrorOffset: Integer;
  Offsets: array[0..300] of Integer;
  OffsetCount, Group: Integer;

begin
  try
    myregexp := pcre_compile('(?P<time>\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})(?P<judge>.{1,3})', 0, @error, @erroroffset, nil);
    if (myregexp <> nil) then begin
      offsetcount := pcre_exec(myregexp, nil, '00:00  X1 90  55KENNY BENNY', Length('00:00  X1 90  55KENNY BENNY'), 0, 0, @offsets[0], High(Offsets));
      if (offsetcount > 0) then begin
        Group := pcre_get_stringnumber(myregexp, 'time');
        WriteLn(Group);
        Group := pcre_get_stringnumber(myregexp, 'judge');
        WriteLn(Group);
      end;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  ReadLn;
end.
```

It prints -7 and 2 instead of 1 and 2.

If I remove RegularExpressionsAPI from the `uses` clause and add the `pcre` unit from my [TPerlRegEx component](http://www.regular-expressions.info/delphi.html), then it does correctly print 1 and 2.

The `RegularExpressionsAPI` in Delphi XE is based on my `pcre` unit, and the `RegularExpressionsCore` unit is based on my `PerlRegEx` unit.  Embarcadero did make some changes to both units.  They also compiled their own OBJ files from the PCRE library that are linked by `RegularExpressionsAPI`.

I have reported this bug as [QC 92497](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=92497)

I have also created a separate report [QC 92498](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=92498) to request that `TGroupCollection.GetItem` raise a more sensible exception when requesting a named group that does not exist.  (This code is in the `RegularExpressions` unit which is based on code written by Vincent Parrett, not myself.)